# VoiceChannel.members returns an empty list in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to create a discord bot that will take a list of users in a voice channel and split it into 2 random teams. The channel's info is successfully downloaded and when I tested some values like channel id, name or type they were returned successfully. Channel name was right, id was right and the type was voice, but for some reason trying to get a list of members always returned an empty array.

```
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@client.command()
async def teams(ctx):
    if ctx.author == client.user:
        return
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    print(channel.members)
    member_names = []
    for x in channel.members:
        member_names.append(x.name)
    msg = ""
    used = []
    team_size = (len(member_names) + len(member_names % 2))/2
    while not len(used) == team_size:
        a = random.randint(0, len(member_names)-1)
        if a not in used:
            msg += str(member_names[a]) + "\n"
            used.append(a)
    await ctx.send(msg)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

My discord.py version is 1.5.1 and python version is 3.8

Comment: What is your discord.py version?

Comment: 1.5.1,  sorry for not including it

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. As Nurqm said there is an intent missing.

With the [Intent `voice_states`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.voice_states) the bot will be able to see voice state changes. This is probably cleaner than `discord.Intents().all()`.

*I would have added that as a comment to Nurqm's answer but I don't have any reputation ;)*

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of discord.py, which is 1.5.1, there is an update about [`Intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#intents). Probably that's why you couldn't get the members. You need to define it:

```py
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```